# How to get Kendo custom filter working?

Tags: php, sql, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get a custom menu filter working in my Kendo grid. Using this code, the menu never loads, just has the spinning circle all the time. I am using the most recent version of kendo. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
 field: "City",
 title: "City",
 width: 110,
 filterable: {
   ui: cityFilter
   }
}    


function cityFilter(element) {
 element.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        severFiltering: true,
        transport: {
           read: "http://localhost:8888/City.php"
               }
        },
        optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
    });
}
```

php:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_pconnect("127.0.0.1", "root", "admin") or die("Unable To Connect To     Database Server");

mysql_select_db("MainDatabase") or die("Unable To Connect To Northwind");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT State_Long FROM MainDatabase.Stations Group by State_Long");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {

    $arr[] = $obj;

}

// add the header line to specify that the content type is JSON
header("Content-type: application/json");

echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($arr). "}";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks valid with your code. Make sure that you have the service available. [Here](http://jsbin.com/ofahod/2/edit) is jsbin with your code which differs only in the transport:

e.g.

```
  function cityFilter(element) {
   element.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
      severFiltering: true,
      transport: {
          read: {
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products"
          }
      },
      },
    dataTextField:"ProductName",
    optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
   });
 }
```

Comment: I got it.  I did this..                 
function cityFilter(element) {
   element.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
            transport: {
                 read: "http://localhost:8888/City.php"
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data"
            }},
            serverFiltering: true,
    dataTextField:"State_Long",
    optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
   });
 }